# PropertyGrid force lose focus

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I have a Windows application which loads several components including a PropertyGrid.

If I make any edits in PropertyGrid and click somewhere else in PropertyGrid, the focus is lost and the property is updated.

But when I make edits in PropertyGrid and click somewhere other than PropertyGrid, the edit cursor is displayed in the TextBox of PropertyGrid and focus is not lost. Is there a possibility to force lose focus when clicked elsewhere?

Comment: You should present what efforts you have made otherwise it's just asking for code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set form's active control to null.

```
private void propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.propertyGrid1.RectangleToScreen(this.DisplayRectangle).Contains(Control.MousePosition))
    {
        if (this.ActiveControl == this.propertyGrid1) { this.ActiveControl = null; }
    }
}
```